# How to get size in bytes of a CLOB column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

How do I get the size in bytes of a `CLOB` column in Oracle?

`LENGTH()` and `DBMS_LOB.getLength()` both return number of characters used in the `CLOB` but I need to know how many bytes are used (I'm dealing with multibyte charactersets).

Comment: Why are you concerned with the size in bytes of the CLOB?

Comment: Not the OP, but in my case I was retrieving CLOBS across a DB link and had to cut them into 4000-byte chunks, and I wanted to know how many chunks I needed for my data.

Comment: this is insane, I want to squeeze Chinese clob into varchar2 and can't do it because I can't determine the size

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After some thinking i came up with this solution:

```
 LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,1,4000)))
```

`SUBSTR` returns only the first 4000 characters (max string size)

`TO_CHAR` converts from `CLOB` to `VARCHAR2`

`LENGTHB` returns the length in Bytes used by the string.

Comment: You could say `LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,3000,1)))+NVL(LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,3000,3001))),0)` - this works up to 6000 bytes but could be extended indefinitely. If you're dealing with multi-byte charsets you need to substring to less than 4000 chars, or you'll get ORA-06501 character string buffer too small. Also note that DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR inverses order of the amount and offset parameters.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331912/performance-of-substr-on-clob

Answer (score 19):

I'm adding my comment as an answer because it solves the original problem for a wider range of cases than the accepted answer. Note: you must still know the maximum length and the approximate proportion of multi-byte characters that your data will have.

If you have a CLOB greater than 4000 bytes, you need to use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR rather than SUBSTR. **Note that the *amount* and *offset* parameters are reversed in DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR.**

Next, you may need to substring an amount less than 4000, because this parameter is the number of *characters*, and if you have multi-byte characters then 4000 characters will be more than 4000 *bytes* long, and you'll get `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small` because the substring result needs to fit in a VARCHAR2 which has a 4000 byte limit. Exactly how many characters you can retrieve depends on the average number of bytes per character in your data.

So my answer is:

```
LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,3000,1)))
+NVL(LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(DBM‌​S_LOB.SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,3000,3001))),0)
+NVL(LENGTHB(TO_CHAR(DBM‌​S_LOB.SUBSTR(<CLOB-Column>,6000,6001))),0)
+...
```

where you add as many chunks as you need to cover your longest CLOB, and adjust the chunk size according to average bytes-per-character of your data.

Comment: See answer by TobiK for the same technique expressed as a loop so that you don't need to check whether you've added enough chunks to cover your largest CLOB.

Comment: So this solution relies on hope and guesswork to avoid ORA-06502 errors? Surely there is a robust way to split a CLOB in to VARCHAR2-sized chunks!

Comment: @PhilHibbs It's enough for my purpose because I only have to deal with French and can make assumptions about the proportion of multibyte characters. But I agree it's unsatisfactory and I'd be delighted to see a better answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one for CLOB sizes bigger than VARCHAR2:

We have to split the CLOB in parts of "VARCHAR2 compatible" sizes, run lengthb through every part of the CLOB data, and summarize all results.

```
declare
   my_sum int;
begin
   for x in ( select COLUMN, ceil(DBMS_LOB.getlength(COLUMN) / 2000) steps from TABLE ) 
   loop
       my_sum := 0;
       for y in 1 .. x.steps
       loop
          my_sum := my_sum + lengthb(dbms_lob.substr( x.COLUMN, 2000, (y-1)*2000+1 ));
          -- some additional output
          dbms_output.put_line('step:' || y );
          dbms_output.put_line('char length:' || DBMS_LOB.getlength(dbms_lob.substr( x.COLUMN, 2000 , (y-1)*2000+1 )));
          dbms_output.put_line('byte length:' || lengthb(dbms_lob.substr( x.COLUMN, 2000, (y-1)*2000+1 )));
          continue;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line('char summary:' || DBMS_LOB.getlength(x.COLUMN));
        dbms_output.put_line('byte summary:' || my_sum);
        continue;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: This is better than my answer if you need the request to be executable in future with no *a priori* knowledge of the maximum possible CLOB size. I'd write it as a function in that case, though.

Comment: I get this error when running the above code: 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 14
ORA-06512: at line 14
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. It was because I had some null values in the CLOB column. It works ok if I just add "where column is not null" in the query.

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution is to cast CLOB to BLOB and then request length of BLOB !

The problem is that Oracle doesn't have a function that cast CLOB to BLOB, but we can simply define a function to do that

```
create or replace
FUNCTION clob2blob (p_in clob) RETURN blob IS 
    v_blob        blob;
    v_desc_offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    v_src_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    v_lang        PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    v_warning     PLS_INTEGER := 0;  
BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob,TRUE);
    dbms_lob.converttoblob
        ( v_blob
        , p_in
        , dbms_lob.getlength(p_in)
        , v_desc_offset
        , v_src_offset
        , dbms_lob.default_csid
        , v_lang
        , v_warning
        );
    RETURN v_blob;
END;
```

The SQL command to use to obtain number of bytes is

```
SELECT length(clob2blob(fieldname)) as nr_bytes
```

or

```
SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(clob2blob(fieldname)) as nr_bytes
```

I have tested this on Oracle 10g without using Unicode(UTF-8).
But I think that this solution must be correct using Unicode(UTF-8) Oracle instance :-)

I want render thanks to Nashev that has posted a solution to convert clob to blob [How convert CLOB to BLOB in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526132/how-convert-clob-to-blob-in-oracle) and to this post written in german (the code is in PL/SQL) [13ter.info.blog](http://13ter.info/blog/?p=364) that give additionally a function to convert blob to clob !

Can somebody test the 2 commands in Unicode(UTF-8) CLOB so I'm sure that this works with Unicode ?

Answer (score 5):

NVL(length(clob_col_name),0) works for me.

Comment: No, `length` returns the length in *characters*, not bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Check the LOB segment name from dba_lobs using the table name.

```
select TABLE_NAME,OWNER,COLUMN_NAME,SEGMENT_NAME from dba_lobs where TABLE_NAME='<<TABLE NAME>>';
```

Now use the segment name to find the bytes used in dba_segments.

```
select s.segment_name, s.partition_name, bytes/1048576 "Size (MB)"
from dba_segments s, dba_lobs l
where s.segment_name = l.segment_name
and s.owner = '<< OWNER >> ' order by s.segment_name, s.partition_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It only works till 4000 byte, What if the clob is bigger than 4000 bytes then we use this

```
declare
v_clob_size clob;

begin

      v_clob_size:= (DBMS_LOB.getlength(v_clob)) / 1024 / 1024;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CLOB Size   ' || v_clob_size);   
end;
```

or

```
select (DBMS_LOB.getlength(your_column_name))/1024/1024 from your_table
```

Comment: But doesn't DMBS_LOG.getlength(...) return the number of characters rather than bytes?