# Retrieving a BLOB using mybatis?

Tags: java, blob, inputstream, mybatis

I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to retrieve a BLOB using mybatis.

I have found a number of examples where the BLOB field is assigned to a byte[] variable in an object. I suppose this is OK if you know that all your BLOB fields will be small and don't mind loading them into memory. However, I have a lot of large BLOBs and I prefer to read them as streams.

I tried assigning the BLOB to a property of type java.io.InputStream, but this did not work. The error message was "No typehandler found for property inputStream" (where "inputStream" is the name of the InputStream property).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is how I did this, but for byte[], for InputStream should be straightforward, but I do think you will need to keep the connection open (I don't know if this could be done with mybatis).

1. Add the Oracle JDBC driver to your project, you will need `mybatis` dependencies too. If you are using Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
       <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
       <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add the [custom BaseTypeHandler for reading byte[] from Oracle BLOB](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) class:

   ```
   @MappedTypes(byte[].class)
   public class OracleBlobTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<byte[]> {
       @Override
       public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, byte[] bytes, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
           // see setBlobAsBytes method from https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/11851/OracleLobHandler.java
           try {
               if (bytes != null) {
                   //prepareLob
                   BLOB blob = BLOB.createTemporary(preparedStatement.getConnection(), true, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

                   //callback.populateLob
                   OutputStream os = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
                   try {
                       os.write(bytes);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       throw new SQLException(e);
                   } finally {
                       try {
                           os.close();
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();//ignore
                       }
                   }
                   preparedStatement.setBlob(i, blob);
               } else {
                   preparedStatement.setBlob(i, (Blob) null);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       /** see getBlobAsBytes method from https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/11851/OracleLobHandler.java */
       private byte[] getBlobAsBytes(BLOB blob) throws SQLException {

           //initializeResourcesBeforeRead
           if(!blob.isTemporary()) {
               blob.open(BLOB.MODE_READONLY);
           }

           //read
           byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1L, (int)blob.length());

           //releaseResourcesAfterRead
           if(blob.isTemporary()) {
               blob.freeTemporary();
           } else if(blob.isOpen()) {
               blob.close();
           }

           return bytes;
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) resultSet.getBlob(columnName);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) resultSet.getBlob(i);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) callableStatement.getBlob(i);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the type handlers package to mybatis configuration. As you can see, I am using spring-mybatis:

   ```
   <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="typeHandlersPackage" value="package.where.customhandler.is" />
   </bean>
   ```
4. And then, *you can read byte[] from Oracle BLOBs from Mybatis*:

   ```
   public class Bean {
       private byte[] file;
   }

   interface class Dao {
       @Select("select file from some_table where id=#{id}")
       Bean getBean(@Param("id") String id);
   }
   ```

This is an adaptation of this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522590/2692914.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no predefined typehandler for InputStream, either

1) You can define your own custom typehandler by extending to BaseTypeHandler and overriding its methods. I'm not sure but you can return an InputStream object i guess. http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers

2) To deal with clobs, i personnaly use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(myClobColumn, size). It's way faster than SUBSTR(), thanks to SO. [Performance of SUBSTR on CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331912/performance-of-substr-on-clob)

Answer (score 0):

I already got this trouble before. You just need to use "selectByExampleWithBLOBs".

> databaseStatementMapper.selectByExampleWithBLOBs(selectIn);

This is a good feature of Mybatis I already faced :))