# How to split a CLOB object using , and : delimiter in Oracle into multiple records

Tags: regex, oracle, substr, oracle12c, regexp-substr

I have a CLOB object sample as shown below. I want to first split this by using delimiter "," and save it in a temporary table for later use.

```
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
```

I want to save the result in the below format in each row.

```
Column_Name
__________________________
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
```

I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR function

```
select 
    regexp_substr('ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0', '[^,]+', 1, 1) Column_Name 
from dual;
```

The above query gives me single record like below

```
Column_Name
__________________________
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using a recursive factored subquery (Oracle 11.2 and above):

```
with inputs ( str ) as (
       select to_clob('ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0')
       from dual
     ),
     prep ( s, n, token, st_pos, end_pos ) as (
       select ',' || str || ',', -1, null, null, 1
         from inputs
       union all
       select s, n+1, substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
              end_pos + 1, instr(s, ',', 1, n+3)
         from prep
         where end_pos != 0
     )
select n as idx, token as column_name
from   prep
where  n > 0;



   IDX COLUMN_NAME
------ ----------------------------
     1 ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
     2 ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
     3 ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
     4 ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
     5 ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
```

**Notes**:

You said CLOB but in your example you extracted from a varchar2 string. I added `to_clob()` to see if/how this works on a CLOB.

I used `instr` and `substr`, as they often (usually?) perform between better and much better than their `regexp` equivalents.

I saved the "index" of each substring within the input string; in some cases the order of the tokens in the input string is important. (Not in your example though, you just had the same token repeated five times.)

If you need better performance, especially if your CLOBs are very large, you may be better off using `dbms_lob.substr` and `dbms_lob.instr` - see [Performance of SUBSTR on CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331912/performance-of-substr-on-clob), especially Alex Poole's answer, and documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#BABEAJAD. Note the syntax differences vs regular `substr` / `instr`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works perfect and it returns CLOB object. Can I return string out of it?

Comment: That would be another benefit of using `dbms_lob.substr`; it takes a `CLOB` input string and it spits out a `VARCHAR2`. Interestingly, this is documented, while I wasn't able to quickly see in the Oracle documentation where it says standard `substr` on a `CLOB` returns `CLOB` (but of course I believe you).

Comment: You are brilliant to share so powerful SQL, save me lot time as we got an issue of string toooo long when using REGEXP_SUBSTR to split a large varchar, thank you...

Comment: This is not working if the string is of length of 10,000 characters. Any other way?

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you really are just trying to parse a long string as per your example.  Include "level" in the select if you need to see the value's index in the list:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmI
d12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:P
mId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0,ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0'
       from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) column_name
   from tbl
   connect by regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level) is not null;

COLUMN_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0
ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0

16 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This gives a performance issue when we use connect by clause.

Comment: This was in case you were really working with a string instead of a clob.

Comment: if the string is larger than 4k, it will throw exception.

Comment: Well, yeah, string literal too long.  No surprise there.