# Bytes are different with clob data on Oracle db and original file

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

I have a png file which is stored as CLOB in oracle db.

and i want to get this data with jdbc template using below code

```
LobHandler lob = new DefaultLobHandler();
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
  "select table from column",
  arr,
  (rs, rowNum) -> lob.getClobAsString(rs, "CLOB_DATA")
);
```

and i am converting to byte array as follows since the encoding in oracle db is  **WE8MSWIN1252**

```
clob.getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
```

however i get the different bytes when i read the file manually with below code and compare with the db data.

```
File path = new File("path/to/file");
Files.readAllBytes(path.toPath());
```

some chars are not loaded correctly. what could be the problem?

Comment: CLOBs are for storing character data. You want to be storing binary data in a BLOB

Comment: Image data should be stored in the database as a BLOB so you avoid problems with character conversion.  Does the image data from the database produce an image?

Comment: yes it does produce an image, and i cannot change it to blob since there are already added data as CLOB in DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a png file which is stored as CLOB in oracle db.

Don't do this. If you have binary data then store it in a binary format, such as a `BLOB`, and don't store it in a format which was not intended for that purpose.

> however i get the different bytes when i read the file manually with below code and compare with the db data.

That's because you're using a `CLOB` for something it wasn't intended for.

> what could be the problem?

The problem is that you are using the wrong data type for your data.

> i cannot change it to blob since there are already added data as CLOB in DB.

Change them all to a `BLOB` and then just [convert the `BLOB` to a `CLOB`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559065/1509264) when you need to get character data out. Trying to do it the other way round (without any encoding of the binary to make is safe to store as a string) is going to continue creating issues like the one you already have.

If you really must use a `CLOB` (please, **DON'T**) then store the binary in an encoded format, such as [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29342860/1509264), which can be safely stored as character data.